# how to resolve the error while saving data - Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed

Tags: c#

```
namespace crud_first
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\testing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Save Successfully...");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didnt specify the column names to insert to.  One of the ones it picked is apparently a binary column.  That is not the correct what to create SQL either.  Use SQL parameters

Answer (score 0):

Correct your query

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (column1, column2, column3) values(@column1, @column2, @column3)"
```

Note: this can have SQL INJECTION.

Use `AddWithValues();`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", txt1.Text.toString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", txt2.Text.toString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column3", txt3.Text.toString());
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1(name, city, country) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";  

I have specified column name in query but it show same error.. and how can i use AddWithValues();, I am new in c#